# How to filter rows based on a condition and if the condition isn't met, grab another row in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

It was hard to think of a title for this question, so hopefully that did make sense.

I will explain further. I have a flow of data from an Excel file and each row has one of two words in the last column. It will either contain "Open" or "Current".

So lets say I have an input that looks like this:

```
NAME | SSN  | TYPE
John | 12345| Current
Katy | 99999| Current
Sam  | 33333| Current
John | 12345| Open
Cody | 55555| Open
```

And the goal is grab only a person once. Each person has their unique id as their SSN. I want to grab `Open` rows if both `Open` and `Current` exist for that person. If only `Current` exists, then grab that.
So the final output should look like this:

```
NAME | SSN  | TYPE
Katy | 99999| Current
Sam  | 33333| Current
John | 12345| Open
Cody | 55555| Open
```

NOTE: As you can see, the first entry for `John` has been removed since he had an `Open` row.

I have attempted this already but it is sloppy and I figure there must be a better way. Here is an image of what I have done:
[Talend flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thT4o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:
[image]

First sort the data by Name, and Type descending (this is important so that for each person, the Open record is on the top); then in the tMap filter it like this:
[image]

```
Numeric.sequence(row2.name, 1, 1) == 1
```

Only let the record through if this is the first we're seeing this name.